# How to format this type of date to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: excel-formula

May I know how to use excel function to formula this type of date ?

[image]

Your kind help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select the cells you want to format.
- Press CTRL+1.
- In the Format Cells box, click the Number tab.
- In the Category list, click Date.

Under Type, pick a date format. Your format will preview in the Sample box with the first date in your data.

Comment: sorry no mentioned I tried use format cell but unfortunately is not working.

Comment: I had tried use MID and LEFT function but when come to single date 1 to 9 my formula will be error due to Mid start_num incorrect position.